# Google Cloud Messaging fails to broadcast message if app is restarted

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In my Android app I use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) to receive messages. Normally this works fine and the onMessage will get called when a message is received. However, on my Huawei Y300 Android 4.1 device, if the app is terminated, either manually or through code, GCM will fail to call the onMessage broadcast receiver. It appears as though GCM keeps an internal reference  using some unique ID to the app's broadcast receiver but if the app is terminated, GCM is unaware of it and tries to send the message to some dead process.

To correct this, you have to either terminate the Google Play services and wait a minute or restart the device. This problem doesn't occur on Android 2.3. On Android 2.3, GCM will still call the onMessage method even if the app is restarted. Is this a known problem and if so, is there a way to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

I had same challenge with Huawei- G510-0200, You need to

1) Check your date and time.

2) sync. your Google Account.

3) find More > "Data Usage"- In "mobile-tab" click on menu and you will see check boxes. re-Check the Auto-sync data check-box. (I am assuming that your device allows this menu. Motorola devices do not have it!)

PS : GCM is now deprecated. Follow the links below :

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/package-summary.html

Comment: GCM is not deprecated. Just the older version of it. I'm using the newest which relies upon Google Play services, so the problem appears to be with Google Play services. Not sure what you mean by the date/time. My app does actually check this and warns the user if it's off by more than 4 days (happens if the battery is removed for an extended period or the battery is empty).

Comment: What version of Google Play services is installed on your device? Mine says 3.2.66

Comment: I see. Tried sync-ing you Google Account then ?

Comment: By default, Google accounts are synced. There should never be a need to do that manually. You can't expect users to do that. It appears to be a bug with Android 4.1/GCM/Google Play services.