# GCM Message not delivered to a particular device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I had been developing an application that used GCM (`GoogleCloudMessaging`). I'm testing the  application using three devices, the Messages are getting delivered to two devices but is not getting delivered to one device.

I tried reinstalling the application and also Checked date and time, sync my Google Account. as seen from the post [Google Cloud Messaging fails to broadcast message if app is restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354381/google-cloud-messaging-fails-to-broadcast-message-if-app-is-restarted?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: What kind of device? please provide more information or noone can help you.

Comment: The device that has issue is huawei mediapad s7-301u loaded with android 4.0.3

Comment: Please post your Android manifest.